# QT disappearing second window

Tags: python, qt

I am new to QT and have used QT 5 for programming in python. I have a main window but when I try to click a button for the second window, it shows but quickly disappears. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

```
def SecondWindow():
    qw = QWidget()
    qw.resize(800, 800)
    qw.move(300, 300)
    qw.show()
```

Comment: Show a [mcve]..

Comment: Change `qw` to `self.qw`: garbage collector

Comment: And `def SecondWindow()` to `def SecondWindow()`, and `SecondWindow()` to  `self.SecondWindow()`

Comment: the variables that are created in a function only exist while the function is called, so in your case qw will only exist during the call of SecondWindow, then it will be deleted and consequently the window will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Python is different than C++: in the latter, the code would work as desired, even if you'd leak the widget. Technically we wouldn't leak the widget since it's accessible from `QApplication::topLevelWidgets`.

In Python, there are no references to `qw` after `SecondWindow` finishes: it is a local variable. Thus the widget is destroyed immediately, since Python first uses reference counting for object lifetime management - and a garbage collector only to collect objects that form cycles, and that's not the case here.

The solution is to keep a reference to the widget you've created:

```
class MyClass(QObject):
  @pyqtSlot()
  def second_windowClick(self):
     self.SecondWindow()

  def SecondWindow(self):
     qw = QWidget()
     qw.resize(800, 800)
     qw.move(300, 300)
     qw.show()
     self.qw = qw
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. But, I receive a:
      File "app.py", line 40, in second_windowClick
        self.SecondWindow()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'SecondWindow'
Abort trap: 6

Comment: @DerrickJones  Both functions above are methods. They belong in a class! I've made it explicit.